# Unhandled exception not caught by handler

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

We've been using unhandled exceptions for ages and we register both `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`
but the following repro case using Drop Event handler does not trigger any unhandled exception handler.

When I throw the exception from UI or task, some handler will be triggered, but form the documentation I don't comprehend why no handler is triggered in my scenario below as I would expect the Dispatcher calling DispatcherUnhandledException

This is VS 2015 with .net 4.5.2

Repro WPF code is very simple, only `AllowDrop` and `Drop` handler. Note: The handlers are registered in the window ctor, same behaviour when doing that in app.xaml.cs.

Just drag & drop any file into it, a message box should appear but it does not.

```
<Window x:Class="unhandledex_wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" AllowDrop="True" Drop="MainWindow_OnDrop">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;using System.Threading.Tasks;using System.Windows;

namespace unhandledex_wpf
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += ( sender, args ) => MessageBox.Show( "Exception" );
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ( sender, args ) => MessageBox.Show( "Exception" );
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += ( sender, args ) =>  MessageBox.Show( "Exception" );

            // works Task.Run( ( )=> { throw new Exception( "foo" ); } );
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnDrop( object sender, DragEventArgs e )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Catch me");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle an exception during a drop event you must handle it within your Drop event handler. Please refer to Peter Ritchie's answer in the following thread on the MSDN forums for more information about why: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8beb1aba-1699-46c7-84dc-38768c7a21f6/treeview-dragdrop-event-ignores-exceptions-help?forum=winforms

Jay Wang (MSFT) has confirmed this in the WPF forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a336acc8-5a29-45aa-b84a-8e235a0f838a/wpf-drop-event-hides-thrown-error?forum=wpf